# How can I extract the year from the datepicker() result in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am not so into JavaScript and I have a doubt related how to correcly pick the date from a field.

So into my page I have an input tag that take a date

```
<input id="dataTrasmissioneAde" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" onchange="aggiornamentoDateAg(this.value)" readonly="readonly" value="" maxlength="10" name="dataTrasmissioneAde">
```

So this input tag would contain something like **25/06/2015** (and now I have the first trivial doubt: is this content of the input tag considered a **String** or a **Date** in JavaScript?)

Ok, then I have a JavaScript function that retrieve the content of the previous input tag by:

```
oDataTrasmissioneAde = $("#dataTrasmissioneAde").datepicker("getDate");
alert("Data trasmissione all'Ade: " + oDataTrasmissioneAde);
```

The **alert()** function show something like this:

> Data trasmissione all'Ade: Thu Jun 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (ora
>   solare Europa occidentale)

So I think, but I am absolutly not true about this assertion, that the input tag having **id="dataTrasmissioneAde"** contains a **String** having value **25/06/2015** and that the **datepicker()** function convert this String into the related date.

Is it true or am I missing something? 
Is it a pure JavaScript function or is it a JQuery function? It seems to me that the function in which it is used is a classi JavaScript function but searching online it seems to me that **datepicker()** is a JQuery function?

How can I extract only the year value from the value of the **oDataTrasmissioneAde** variable (obtained by the use of the **datepicker()** function) ?

So in the previous case I have to obtain the **2015** value.

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
oDataTrasmissioneAde = $("#dataTrasmissioneAde").datepicker("getDate");

var myDate = new Date(oDataTrasmissioneAde );

alert ( myDate.getFullYear() );
```

You can do whatever you want later with the Date object.

Answer (score 2):

`datePicker()` is part of jQuery UI. And yes, calling `.getDate()` retrieves the set date and turns it into a JavaScript date object.

To get the year:

```
$("#dataTrasmissioneAde").datepicker("getDate").getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, tested and works 100%

```
<script>


    var x = new Date(oDataTrasmissioneAde+"");
        alert(x.getUTCFullYear());   //x.getUTCFullYear() contains year

</script>
```